# Parsing XML using android sax parser

Tags: android, xml, sax, xml-parsing

below is a sample structure of the XML I'm trying to parse using the Android SAX parsing approach in this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html#list8).

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <child>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
        </child>
        <child>
            <id></id>
            <name> </name>
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <child>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
        </child>
    </parent>
    ...
</root>
```

I have two classes named `Parent` and `Child`. Parent has a field which is a list of Child objects, such as this.

Parent

```
public class Parent {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Child> childList;

    //constructor, getters and setters

    // more code

}
```

Child

```
public class Child {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    //constructor, getters and setters

    // more code

}
```

So I created a Parent object to store the parsed data. In the code below I can get the `name` and `id` element of `parent` but I cant figure out how to parse the `child` elements and their own child elements. I dont know if this is the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Can someone show me a way?

```
public class AndroidSaxFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {

    public AndroidSaxFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
        super(feedUrl);
    }

    public List<Parent> parse() {

        final Parent current = new Parent();
        RootElement root = new RootElement("root");
        final List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        Element parent = root.getChild("parent");

        parent.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {
            public void end() {
                parents.add(current.copy());
            }
        });

        parent .getChild("id").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
            public void end(String body) {
                current.setId(body);
            }
        });

        parent .getChild("name").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
            public void end(String body) {
                current.setName(body);
            }
        });

        try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8,
                    root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return parents ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parent.getChild("child").getChild("id").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
            public void end(String body) {
                current.setChildId(body);
            }
        });
parent.getChild("child").getChild("name").setEndTextElementListener(
                new EndTextElementListener() {
            public void end(String body) {
                current.setChildName(body);
            }
        });
```